# How to install LaTeXML in Windows?

Tags: installing, latexml

Can someone please provide a step by step instruction to how to install and use LaTeXML in Windows? I reached their [official site](https://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/) for instructions but couldn't understand any.

Any help will be  appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands that is a wide question since each person will have a different opinion as to what is best for you !!

I suggest your question hints at a novice user and the "best" solution would likely include more than you need to test if it does what you expect. At this stage a full Tex system is probably overkill and can be added later. 
Back to the answer

1) Ideally you will install TeX first. There are two main variants one is TeX Live a large multi GB download but a **single user** basic [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/download) may be simpler and expands as you use more TeX variations of packages. AVOID installing as admin just install as recommended single basic user. Follow the instructions and test it works thoroughly before loading the following, since LaTeXml hooks into the TeX installation later.

2) You need the Perl language (engine) that is NOT included with MiKTeX and more powerful than the one in TeX Live. The latexml recommended version is Strawberry Perl. However note that ImageMagick preference is ActivePerl (just 1 of many conflicts).

So Install http://strawberryperl.com/ the landing page offers alternatives.
You must have Perl version 5.1 or greater and ImageMagick 6.6 or above installed on your system for PerlMagick to build properly. Ensure MiKTeX AND Perl AND Magick are the same "bitness" for your windows check if your windows **system** (not hardware) is 32 or 64 bit then download all 3 accordingly try not to mix bitness (although I personally favour 32bit for portable compatible use)

3) The graphics options are wide (14 variations) from ImageMagick alone. 32 or 64 bit **dynamic at 16 bits-per-pixel** component is the preferred option. https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

At this point you should have installed most of the core engines and need to check they are working well before adding the latexml components so at a standard windows command prompt> enter each of the following

`latex -version`
`perl -version`
`magick -version`

ALL three MUST give you good version feedback before you proceed.

4) the magick:perl link appears to be down so cant advise on that component

5) follow the latexml perl instructions to proceed you only need the extra prerequisites if you loaded active perl since they are included in strawberry perl

6) Once Perl is setup you need to run cpan LaTeXML  following any instructions if you have problems at this point you need to log them at https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/